# Solve integral symbolically by isolating integrand in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I was wondering why sympy won't solve the following problem:

```
from sympy import *
ss = symbols('s', real = True)
a = symbols('a', real = True)
f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')
eq = Integral(a*g(ss) + f(ss),(ss,0,oo))
solve(eq, a)
```

The return is an empty solution list. I want to tell sympy enough stuff so that I get as a solution:

```
-1*Integral(f(ss),(ss,0,oo))/Integral(g(ss),(ss,0,oo))
```

That is, its safe to assume integrals converge, are real-valued and non-zero.
Is there any other assumption/function I can use to get the desired output?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the solution you're expecting? Cause it seems to me that to get this solution, `a` should be outside the integral. Unless you have defined `oo` to be 1.

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong. I have edited with what I would expect now.

Comment: Provide also the declarations for `ss` and `oo`

Comment: Done. `oo` is imported from sympy

Comment: Nothing in the code gives an "empty solution list" so something is missing.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin OP had `solve(eq, a)` at the end, but accidentally deleted it in the edit.

Comment: Yes sorry, I added it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about the expected result is still inaccurate. For the equation to have a solution, `Integral(g(ss),(ss,0,oo))` must be guaranteed to be real and non-zero, which is in no way implied by your equations, so no result is returned.

Further, it appears that if you want to solve equations involving an `Integral`, you need to use `doit`. Take a look below

```python
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real = True)
a = symbols('a', real = True)
f = Function('f')

eq = a+Integral(f(x), (x, 0, oo))
print('Eq.1', solve(eq, a))

eq2 = Integral(a+f(x), (x, 0, oo))
print('Eq.2', solve(eq2.doit(), a))

eq3 = Integral(a+f(x), (x, 0, 1))
print('Eq.3', solve(eq3.doit(), a))

eq4 = Integral(a+2, (x, 0, 3))
print('Eq.4', solve(eq4, a))
print('Eq.4', solve(eq4.doit(), a))
```

Output:

```
Eq.1 [-Integral(f(x), (x, 0, oo))]
Eq.2 []
Eq.3 []
Eq.4 []
Eq.4 [-2]
```

Note that eq.1 **is** solvable, in the sense that you can move `a` on one side of the equation since it is not inside a limit (integrals with infinite bounds are shorthand for the limit of an integral with the respective bound approaching infinity). However, eq.2 and eq.3 are **not** solvable, because the limit of a sum is equal to the sum of the limits only if they converge to a real number (and, in your case, there is no guarantee that they do).

Finally, eq.4 is trivially solvable, but you have to use `doit`. In eq.1 you can get away without it.

---

That said, you can "overcome" the formalism, using [`expand`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=expand#sympy.core.function.expand). Take a look below.

```python
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real = True)
a = symbols('a', real = True)
f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

eq5 = a+Integral(a+f(x), (x, 0, 1))
print('Eq.5', solve(eq5.expand().doit(), a))

eq6 = Integral(a+f(x), (x, 0, 1))
print('Eq.6', solve(eq6.expand().doit(), a))

eq7 = Integral(a*g(x)+f(x), (x, 0, oo))
print('Eq.7', solve(eq7.expand().doit(), a))
```

Output:

```
Eq.5 [-Integral(f(x), (x, 0, 1))/2]
Eq.6 [-Integral(f(x), (x, 0, 1))]
Eq.7 [-Integral(f(x), (x, 0, oo))/Integral(g(x), (x, 0, oo))]
```

This works because it allows certain operations, by playing fast and loose with the details. **But**, it still doesn't work, when the results are plain-wrong (try to use `oo` as the upper bound in eq.6 or eq.7).

Comment: I guess then my follow up question is: how do I tell sympy I want to assume that the integral converges and is real? I have a more complicated case where I would like sympy to understand that I want it to solve out for terms which are constant inside the integral.

Comment: Thanks, your answer solves the problem. It seems doit() is crucial to the trick. I wonder though, how can we make it faster for more complex expressions? It seems sympy does not figure out quickly the terms that are constant so that it can pull it off.

Comment: @user191919 I don't think you can do much. Sympy is python based, so it is naturally slow. You can try to use symengine (written in C++ and hence compiled) along with sympy.

Answer (score 0):

This is your equation:

```
In [9]: eq
Out[9]: 
∞                   
⌠                   
⎮ (a⋅g(s) + f(s)) ds
⌡                   
0
```

You would like to solve for `a` to make this expression equal to zero. We can rearrange this expression to extract `a` so that `solve` understands how to isolate `a`:

```
In [10]: eq.expand()
Out[10]: 
∞                   
⌠                   
⎮ (a⋅g(s) + f(s)) ds
⌡                   
0                   

In [11]: eq.expand(force=True)
Out[11]: 
∞             ∞        
⌠             ⌠        
⎮ a⋅g(s) ds + ⎮ f(s) ds
⌡             ⌡        
0             0        

In [12]: factor_terms(eq.expand(force=True))
Out[12]: 
  ∞           ∞        
  ⌠           ⌠        
a⋅⎮ g(s) ds + ⎮ f(s) ds
  ⌡           ⌡        
  0           0        

In [13]: solve(factor_terms(eq.expand(force=True)), a)
Out[13]: 
⎡ ∞         ⎤
⎢ ⌠         ⎥
⎢-⎮ f(s) ds ⎥
⎢ ⌡         ⎥
⎢ 0         ⎥
⎢───────────⎥
⎢ ∞         ⎥
⎢ ⌠         ⎥
⎢ ⎮ g(s) ds ⎥
⎢ ⌡         ⎥
⎣ 0         ⎦
```

We have to use `force=True` because `expand` will not presume to know that an integral with an upper limit of `oo` converges and splitting the integral into two integrals might turn a converging integral into a sum of non-converging integrals.